# Are Regular Languages (as we represent by Finite State Machines) Fields?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I am aware that we can do set operations on them, and sets are fields. Are regular languages also mathematical fields?

Comment: Of course a field can be viewed as a set, but under what interpretation is a set a field?

Comment: Under what operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the set of regular languages is not a field, but it is a [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Concrete_Boolean_algebras).  It also qualifies as a [field of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) -- but note that the term "field of sets" has nothing to do with the notion of a "field"; it's an unfortunate name collision.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure).